# Buffers between center points of irregular polygons

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, road

I'm having some problems, I hope some of you have some experience with buffers :)

I have the road network of a city (40.000 polygons approx), and I am trying to create a buffer between the central point of the line between each segment of the road that crosses (perpendicularly). My goal is to create a buffer that has a different area on each side of it (having the polygon inside the buffer). This is because the road network is not uniform, so I cannot create a buffer with a specific radius that means the same for each and every road segment.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: A road network as... polygons? From what I'm used to, road networks are made up of lines, or arcs, not polygons. Could you please refine your question a little?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have the road segment from side to side of the pedestrian side to the other side as a polygons.

Comment: That's a major information (!), you should add it (with any other relevant information?) to your main question by clicking the small 'edit' text button on the bottom of your question. And maybe adding a screenshot and a sketch of what your desired output should look like...